# BricsCAD programming with c# ERROR : System.BadImageFormatException and system.io.filenotfoundexception

Tags: c#, cad

I have a problem with programming BricsCAD with c# in visual studio 2017. Firstly i hava a error

> "'System.BadImageFormatException' ocurred in System.Windows.Forum.dll
>   // additional information:'TD_Mgd Version=3.6.0.0 Culture=Neutral
>   PublicKeyToken=null'"

when running C# program.
Than i changed .NET version but i had another error like that "system.io.filenotfoundexception" at same dll as TD_Mgd.
I have no solution for this. If someone has experience for bricscad programming with c# please help me.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BricscadApp.AcadApplication cadApp = new BricscadApp.AcadApplication();

        cadApp = (BricscadApp.AcadApplication)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("BricscadApp.AcadApplication");
        cadApp.Visible = true;
        BricscadApp.AcadDocument ThisDrawing = cadApp.ActiveDocument;
        Point2d asd = new Point2d(10, 20);
        Point2d asdf = new Point2d(25, 30);
        cadApp.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddLine(asd, asdf);
    }
}
```

Comment: BadImageFormatException usually means, that you are trying to load a x86 dll in a x64 project or vice versa. I would guess that the BricsCAD dlls are x64 only and you try to use it in an x86 or AnyCPU Project.

Comment: Have you checked that the required dlls (native and wrapper) are actually in the build folder so that they could be potentially loaded?

Comment: I tried your commend but i have another error like before one : system.io.filenotfoundexception